# Programming for Nokia phone?

Tags: symbian, nokia

What is best way to develop for nokia phones ?

symbian programing or html applications ?

how to start symbian programming. i am not able to find the nokia carbide software anymore. which software is used to program ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, Symbian programming is the way to go for Nokia applications because you can create more visually appealing applications in less time using QT.  Check out their QT platform which makes it easier for developers to start programming for Nokia devices and deploy to OVI store. You may want to start at http://www.forum.nokia.com/Develop/Qt/

If you want to know your options and the tools associated with them (Either developing in Symbian, Web or Java), you can check out their Developer website at http://www.forum.nokia.com/Develop/

Comment: QT is only for nokia right ? or can i port it to other mobiles also ?

Comment: Maybe if your app is not complicated it can work on other brand and devices, but the problem with Symbian development is that the GUI layer is not standardized, (You have Nokia Series 60 and 80, or the UIQ used by Sony Ericsson, etc) so if you developing visuals, you may need some porting so that it'll work on your target devices.  Good thing is the lower level logic should be almost the same (using Symbian).

Answer (score 1):

here the downloadlinks:

- [platform-sdk](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/4a7149a5-95a5-4726-913a-3c6f21eb65a5/S60-SDK-0616-3.0-mr.html)
- [carbice.c++](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/dbb8841d-832c-43a6-be13-f78119a2b4cb.html)

hope that helps